# VertxTestContext completing in 4.0.0

Tags: junit, vert.x

In previous versions, I could deploy Verticle in the following code.

```kotlin
  @BeforeEach
  fun deploy(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
    val web = vertx.deployVerticle(WebVerticle())
    val database = vertx.deployVerticle(DatabaseVerticle())
    CompositeFuture.all(web, database).handler = testContext.succeeding {
      testContext.completeNow()
    }
  }
```

But in `4.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, the `handler` is `val`, there's only a `get` method.

I have tried these methods.

```kotlin
  CompositeFuture.all(web, database).onSuccess {
    testContext.succeeding<Any> {
      testContext.completeNow()
    }
  }

  // Or

  CompositeFuture.all(web, database).onSuccess {
    testContext.completing<Any>()
  }

  // Or

  CompositeFuture.all(web, database).onComplete {
    testContext.succeeding<Any> {
      testContext.completeNow()
    }
  }
```

Result: `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`. He has been waiting for this method to end and I don't know how to deal with it

How can I write code to get the same effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you write your code in Kotlin, it would be even more simple to use the corresponding "...Await" functions, available in the modules:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-lang-kotlin</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-milestone4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-milestone4</version>
</dependency>
```

This way you are enabled to use the function *deployVerticleAwait* instead. But you must run this code wihtin a coroutine. A further, simple way is to use extension functions for test executing purposes, like:

```
fun Vertx.testAsync(testContext: VertxTestContext, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
        CoroutineScope(this.dispatcher()).launch {
            runCatching { block(this) }.onSuccess { testContext.completeNow() }.onFailure { testContext.failNow(it) }
        }
    }
```

An a final test function then can look like:

```
@Test
internal fun my_test(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) =
    vertx.testAsync(testContext) {
        // Do some things within this coroutine
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what i mean

Comment: I think i did understand, but i was not sure if you know that there is a more simple alternative to callbacks with Kotlin. But to stay on your base question, with 4.0.0-milestone4 the handler has a setter. The code "CompositeFuture.all(emptyList()).handler = testContext.completing()" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cross-posted to the Vert.x users mailing list I am replying there instead.